# IE10 with disabled JS executes manually entered `onmousedown`

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, security-policy

In IE10 I've disabled JS execution by setting maximum security level (IE11 also affected).

Then I add or edit `onmousedown` attribute on any element on any site (for example, `body` element on `www.google.com`).

```html
<body onmousedown="alert('Hello')">...</body>
```

And so I get an alert when clicking anywhere.

Is it expected behavior or bug?

Comment: Maybe developer console makes automatic turn on JS on page?

Comment: @denisoid, nope, i cannot even `2+2` in console.

Comment: Only an IE developer can come here and confirm this, but it's obviously a terrible bug

Comment: Is this working with mouseevents and alert only, or all event attribute and any javascript?

Comment: @derylius, didn't test much, but I'm pretty sure that both may vary widely. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I have only IE11 to test with but I will take a look in a few days and may sign back the results

Comment: I've already tested IE11 and updated my question =) No good.

Comment: So I made some testing as well, and it seems to be more complex, as I've been able to call a predeclared function with the function-call added manually but couldn't call any injected function, nor could assign any event listener, which makes me think that the way they implemented the enabling/disabling of javascript, is that it simply blocks the execution of any function, which work just fine, but when they implemented the dev-tools they left it opened for the devs to inject code. Maybe it's a bug, maybe an undocumented feature, but as long as it can't be exploited by XSS I would say latter.

Comment: So as it stands for any further research we should have a source or an MS dev as Axel pointed out. Try to fill a bug report if it's annoying you, otherwise just don't use it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd> has its own **Disable menu** in IE10:

> This menu helps you test how users would experience your site based on how they have configured their browser. The following commands are available in the Disable menu:
>
> **Script**
>
> Disable all scripts on a webpage. This command must be clicked again to enable all scripts. When selected, the command is set and causes the page to refresh. This command is not available if Internet Security has Protected Mode set to On. To activate this command, set Protected Mode to Off.
>
> **Popup Blocker**
>
> Disable all pop-up blockers so that pop-ups are allowed on this website. This command must be selected again to enable pop-up blockers. This command is not available if Internet Security has Protected Mode set to On. To activate this command, set Protected Mode to Off.
>
> **All CSS**
>
> Disable all Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) on the page. Click again to enable all CSS. When selected, the command is set and causes the page to refresh to reflect the selection. This command will be re-enabled when a webpage refreshes.

This is deprecated in IE11:

> There are no plans at this time to bring back the disable menu from IE10 <kbd>F12</kbd>. You can disable most of the features previously in the <kbd>F12</kbd> disable menu from the Internet Options advanced and security options.

**References**

- [F12 Developer Tools User Interface Reference: Disable menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565626#disableMenu)
- [[IE11] [Feature request] Bring back Disable menu in F12 developer tools](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/791874/ie11-feature-request-bring-back-disable-menu-in-f12-developer-tools)
- [f12.exe orphaned processes in Tasksmanager when no Developer tools open](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796265/f12-exe-orphaned-processes-in-tasksmanager-when-no-developer-tools-open)